# How to add to the existing URL parameter of a link on mouseenter?

Tags: jquery

Links to my site contain a few URL parameters, including one that identifies the user's origin. We've named this URL parameter "r" for "referrer."

An example link with this parameter would look like this:

*example.com/?r=google-search&utm_source=google*

When linking from one page on my site to a specific page called "Exit Banner", I need to add "_exitbanner" to the "r" value within that link on the original page, but not fully replace it, as it contains the referrer.

So in the previous example, a link from the homepage to the Exit Banner page would look like:

*example.com/?r=google-search**_exitbanner**&utm_source=google*

I know I can append text to the overall URL, but not how to append text only to a *specific* parameter within it.

Here is my current jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.track-click").one('mouseenter', function () {
        $("a.track-click").attr("href",function(n, v){
            return v + "_exitbanner";
        });
    });
});
```

And the link it will effect:

```
<a href="https://example.com/?r=google" class="track-click">https://example.com/?r=google</a>
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the href attribute of the element or the actual URL in the browser window?

Comment: is v  the whole URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several way to do it.. Assuming `r` is the first param, and that there are other params coming up, one way is to use the regex pattern `\?r=[^&]+` which means *take from ?r= until you reach the character & to replace `r=xxxx`to `r=xxxx_exitbanner`* as follows

```
$("a.track-click").attr("href",function(n, v){
    var theMatch = v.match(/\?r=[^&]+/); //to avoid an exception.
    return v.replace(theMatch && theMatch[0], theMatch[0] + '_exitbanner')        
});
```

Comment: I think if you change it to v.replace(theMatch && theMatch[0], '?' + theMatch + '_exitbanner') it would be the best answer

Comment: oops you just updated while i was typing. This is the best answer now. deleted mine.

Comment: hehe yes, I updated after I saw your comment on your post! Thanks buddy!